# Duplicate Customer Created when using PUT endpoint - Square Connect

Tags: python, square

I created a helper function to update customer data in a class. When I call the function it updates all the information. If I try it again on my tests... it creates a new entry into the customer database, creating a duplicate..

I cant figure out if its my logic or what I am doing wrong. Can someone assist.

I am using the HTTP requests package

**Initiate class**

```
self.customer = Sq_Customer(
            first_name = 'Testy',
            last_name = 'McTesty',
            email = 'McTesty@testy.com',
            phone= '123-456-7890'
            )
```

**Update user JSON and Function call**

```
    self.data = {
                'given_name': 'Dummy',
                'email_address': dummy_account@testing.com',
                'address': {
                    'address_line_1': '1234 Main Street',
                    'address_line_2': '',
                    'locality': 'New York',
                    'administrative_district_level_1': 'NY',
                    'postal_code': '11413',
                    'country': 'US'
                }
            }


 self.update_customer = self.customer.update_customer_acct(Customer ID, self.data)
```

**My Helper Function**

```
def update_customer_acct(self, user_id, data):
        '''
        Update Customer information.
        '''
        self.customer = self.get_customer(user_id)
        if self.customer['customer']['id'] == user_id:
            self.update_customer_data = self.connect.put('/v2/customers/' + user_id, data)
            return self.__sqware_json_decoder(self.update_customer_data)
        else:
            return '{}'.format('There is no account associated with that ID.')
```

Comment: What is going on with `get_customer`? it seems like that is an extra step that might be messing something up.

Comment: @tristansokol  I know.  It uses the RetrieveCustomer from the V2 API to get user data for the ID... not the best implementation. and I will be fixing that.

Comment: but you have the id when you call `update_customer_acct`?

Comment: @tristansokol yes.. I just wanted to make sure that the ID when passed to the update_customer_acct is checked and correct. Im still learning. It is an extra step. I thought about your question, and think Im gonna remove that portion.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to be doing anything for you besides slowing you down. And since I don't know what is in that function it seems like it might be making your duplicates as well

Comment: @tristansokol Im still learning. I appreciate your help and time. Im gonna go back and look at what Im doing and refactor somethings.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the email and there was no longer a duplicate. It's an issue with me creating a customer during the test.  When the email is changed it creates a new account.  Thanks again.

Comment: This sounds like a bad API semantic/data model smell. If the email is a primary identifier of accounts it should handle the PUT as an update of an existing account if the email exists already. (and PUT is often used to signal an update anyway). I'd be tempted to report this to the Square Connect API devs as ambiguous/confusing API behavior.